# Reactive Functions in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm stuck trying to understand how I can get reactive values when using functions in Vue.

I have a simple case like so:

```
 <v-simple-checkbox :value="isSelected(item)" @input="toggleSelect(item)" />
```

`isSelected` and `toggleSelect` are methods (or rather functions exposed via Vue Composition API).

they are defined as so:

```
  let selection = {};

  function toggleSelect(item) {       
    selection[item.id] = !selection[item.id]
  }

  function isSelected(item) {
    return !!selection[item.id];
  }

  return {
     isSelected,
     toggleSelect,
     other exposed things...
  }
```

When clicking the checkbox, I see that all state is updated.
But as `:value` binds to a function. it doesn't trigger update of the view.

This is basically the issue of "computed with arguments" and I don't find any real answer to it.

I've tried with `$forceUpdate` but no luck there either.

Comment: can you share any codepen plz.

Comment: What are you using to experiment with composition API ? https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api ?

Answer (score 4):

> But as `:value` binds to a function, it doesn't trigger update of the view.

This is simply not true. It doesn't matter whether you bind to an inline JS expression (like `:value="!!selection[item.id]"`) or to a function returning result of the same expression as in your example. Vue just executes render function (compiled from template) and monitors all reactive data. If some reactive data is used during rendering, Vue knows that whenever this data changes in the future, it should run re-render. And it doesn't matter whether data is "touched" by simple expression or calling function or calling multiple nested functions. Doesn't matter at all. **What matters is whether your data is reactive**

For `selection` to be reactive, you must create it and use it like this:

```js
const state = reactive({
  selection: {}
})

function toggleSelect(item) {       
    state.selection[item.id] = !state.selection[item.id]
  }

  function isSelected(item) {
    return !!state.selection[item.id];
  }
```

Don't forget to `import { reactive } from '@vue/composition-api'`

### Update

I assume you are using [this package](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api) for your experiments. It's new composition API but implemented on top of Vue 2. Because of this, is has same [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). Problem in this case is adding new properties to empty object `selection`. After adding initial values, code works as expected....

```js
const state = reactive({
      selection: {
        1: false,
        2: true
      }
    });
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactive-functions-in-vue-qqssb)

In Vue 3 this won't be needed as it will use proxies for change detection...

Comment: This has no effect, just because the state used is reactive does not make the call to the function reactive. (I just tried this, and no difference)

Comment: Then there is some other problem but I'm pretty sure it will not work without it. Doesn't matter if you use function or not, important is reactive state is "touched" when the component is rendered... Mayby you should add more code or create codepen/sandbox...

Comment: binding the checkbox directly to this reactive state solved it, it stops working when binding to the functions.

Comment: @RogerJohansson But problem is not in using functions in bindings. It's still same old problem of adding properties to object of Vue 2. Updated my answer and working demo...